# INSERT INTO 3 tables joined with one table at once query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert into, Update 3 tables joined with one table at once query using PHP, so I have the table "commandetb" who have the foreign key of tables = fournisseurtb, marchetb and marchetb table has a foreign key of datetb, so I have a form that has inputs for nomF, adrF, telF from fournisseurtb also objet_marche from marchetb and the last date_limite & heure_limite from datetb. who can help me to resolve this problem I appreciate that. here's the script :

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `commandetb`(`date_cmd`,ID_marche,ID_f) VALUES('hhhh',,);
          INSERT INTO `fournisseurtb`(`nomF`,`adrF`,`telF`) VALUES(:znomF,:zadrF,:ztelF);
          INSERT INTO `marchetb`(`objet_marche`,ID_date) VALUES(:zobjet,LAST_INSERT_ID()) ";
    $stmt=$connectDB->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':znomF',$nomSoc);
    $stmt->bindValue(':zadrF',$adrSoc);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ztelF',$telSoc);
    $stmt->bindValue(':zobjet',$objet);
    
    $exec=$stmt->execute();

    if ($exec) {
        $sql2="INSERT INTO `datetb` (`date_limite`,`heure_limite`) VALUES(:zdateLimite,:zheureLimite)";
        $stmt2=$connectDB->prepare($sql2);
        $stmt2->bindValue(':zdateLimite',$dateLimite);
        $stmt2->bindValue(':zheureLimite',$heureLimite);
        $exec2=$stmt2->execute();
        if ($exec2) {
            $_SESSION['succesMessage']='La lettre est ajouté avec succes';
        }
    }
    else {
            $_SESSION['errorMessage']='il ya un problem d\'ajout, verifiez svp!';
        }
```

Comment: *I'm trying to insert into, Update 3 tables joined with one table at once query* Either INSERT or UPDATE. Decide. *Update 3 tables joined with one table at once query* Easily. Multiple-table UPDATE exists in MySQL. Rather than INSERT.

Comment: You may write stored procedure which accepts ALL data and performs ALL needed operations realizing any logic you need. From PHP side only one query `CALL proc({parameters})` wil be executed.

Comment: @Akina thanks for that, I'll try it right now, thank you for your time sir

Answer (score 0):

I use the stored procedure, but the problem doesn't resolve:
**Mysql code:**

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE add_lettre(nomf varchar(50), adrf varchar(255), telf varchar(25), objetMarche varchar(500), dLimite varchar(25), hLimite varchar(25))
```

BEGIN
INSERT INTO fournisseurtb(nomF,adrF,telF) VALUES(nomf,adrf,telf);
INSERT INTO marchetb(objet_marche, ID_date) VALUES(objetMarche, LAST_INSERT_ID());
INSERT INTO datetb (date_limite,heure_limite) VALUES(dLimite,hLimite);
END

**PHP code :**

```
$sql="CALL add_lettre(':znomF',':zadrF',':ztelF','zobjet',':zdateLimite',':zheureLimite')";
    $stmt=$connectDB->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':znomF',$nomSoc);
    $stmt->bindValue(':zadrF',$adrSoc);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ztelF',$telSoc);
    $stmt->bindValue(':zobjet',$objet);
    $stmt2->bindValue(':zdateLimite',$dateLimite);
    $stmt2->bindValue(':zheureLimite',$heureLimite);
    
    $exec=$stmt->execute();

    if ($exec) {
        
        $_SESSION['succesMessage']='La lettre est ajouté avec succes';
        
    }
    else {
            $_SESSION['errorMessage']='il ya un problem d\'ajout, verifiez svp!';
        }
```